# OCaml specific Hashtbl type

Tags: types, ocaml, hashtable, variant

This is probably a silly question, but I want to define a type like this:

```
type bla = Bla of (string, bla) Hashtbl
```

However, it gives me a parse error, no matter what I do. In essence, I want `Bla` to hold
hashtable from `string` to `bla` again. What am I exactly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashtbl is a module. The (non-functorial) type that it defines is `('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t`:

```
# type bla = Bla of (string, bla) Hashtbl.t;;
type bla = Bla of (string, bla) Hashtbl.t
```